# Mifare Classic 1k - Error function ReadBlock

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I am creating an application that allows me to read data in different tags. I am currently working with a tag `Mifare Classic 1k`.

To verify that the reading of my data is correct, I use the official application `NXP` and have found some differences in the interpretation of data.

In my code, I read all the blocks in each sector using the `ReadBlock`. All data are read properly apart the 3rd block of each sector. In fact, according to `NXP` it should look something like this: `ffffffffffffff078069ffffffffffff`, but my application reads the following block: `0000000000000000078069ffffffffffff`. I do not know if it is `Nxp`'s application error or something, but when I read the block, I use a function that already exists and wasn't created by me.

Can anyone give me clarification on?

Answer (score 2):

When you read the sector trailer (i.e. the last block of a sector), the contents of key A will always be returned as all-zeroes. The same holds for key B when it is set to be not readable.
(However, because you were able to read that block, you know the key, so you can derive what is actually stored in the chip.)